# draggable rect in svg drags only diagnolly on the screen

Tags: svg, draggable

I tried making a small program where in I wrote code to drag a rectangle in svg. The program is quite simple. My problem is that the rectangle drags only diagnolly on the screen and not on the entire web page.

Here is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="100%" height="100%"
 onload="Init( evt )" >

<script type="text/ecmascript">
   //<![CDATA[
var svgDocument;
var svgRoot;
var newP;
var bmousedown=0;
var myCirc;

function Init(evt){

svgRoot= document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];


   newP = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
   myCirc = document.getElementById("mycirc");
   }

function getMouse(evt){
   var position = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
   position.x = evt.clientX;
   position.y = evt.clientY;
   return position;
   }

function onMouseDown(evt){
   bmousedown=1;
   newP=getMouse(evt);
   doUpdate();
   }

function onMouseMove(evt){
   if(bmousedown){
       newP=getMouse(evt);
       doUpdate();
       }
   }

function onMouseUp(evt){
   bmousedown=0;
   }

function doUpdate(){
   myCirc.setAttributeNS(null, "x", newP.x );
   myCirc.setAttributeNS(null, "y", newP.y );
   }

// ]]></script>


<rect id="mycirc" fill: #bbeeff" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="80"

   pointer-events="visible"
   onmousedown="onMouseDown(evt)"
   onmousemove="onMouseMove(evt)"
   onmouseup="onMouseUp(evt)"/>

</svg>
```

Please help me as I am unable to understand why does it not move on the entire screen.

Comment: it doesn't seem to drag at all. can you set up a working example, say using [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i see the problem recreated on firefox, but it's not a single problem, your code is all over the place. i suggest going back to the drawing board before posting specific questions.

i'd also recommend a [good reference on SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Tutorial) or using a [JS vector graphics library](http://raphaeljs.com/), as it would simplify things a little and will ease up the development a lot, if you're not interested in getting down to the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/5GHJs/

The mistakes I think you made:

- `onload="Init( evt )"`  makes the variable `evt` global, a bad and useless thing to have. All the functions are also global, but this should be ok for this example.
- the function calls for `onmousedown` etc. were using this global `evt`. (wrong). In order to get the correct event for each call you need to register some handlers.